# CATransition in AppDelegate - didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: iphone, catransition

I've implemented this code in another app, and it **worked great**. Now, the same code is **not** working here (I **am** importing QuartzCore framewok)... The log message **IS** called. Could anyone help me please? Thanks in advance. This is my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.5];

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.delegate = self;
    transition.duration = 1.5;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;

    [[window layer] addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished: (BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"Animation did stop!");
}
```

Comment: is this code meant to fade out the default.png image and fade in your view?

Comment: Yes it does. What would be the best thing to do? Add a UIImageView with the same Default.png image in the AppDelegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move:

```
    [[window layer] addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

below:

```
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

You're explicitly creating the animation, but you're applying the animation "Before" you want to add the Subview to the Window. By placing it below, you tell the Window that you want to animate the positioning of the subview.

Comment: Sorry, move [[window layer] addAnimation:transition forKey:nil]; below the addSubview line and it should. There is no reason why this animation should not work. I do something similar, and it works on my end..